# error while creating an object with Postman rest api [RAILS 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create an object of my rails application using Postman REST API, but getting the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in GroupsController#create
```

My controller:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_group, only: [:show]
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

def show
    render json: @group 
end

def new
    @group = Group.new
end

def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    if @group.save
            render json: @group
            else
        render json: @group.errors
    end
end

private
def set_group
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
end
def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
end

end
```

[image]

I found many similar questions but they were related with the form, but I am not using it!
Any feedback is appreciated.

**Last update**

I could fix this error by :

```
    def group_params
         params.fetch(:group, {}).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
    end
```

But now it says these fields cannot be empty even if they exist. Do I send wrong the params[:group]?

Log file:

```
Started POST "/groups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-14 22:21:26 +0100
Processing by GroupsController#create as */*
[1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: the name of param in Postman is "groups" not "group".

Comment: still not working. the error comes from the controller I guess. Any way in Postman I have <groups></groups> as in the picture, but I guess it should be <group></group> instead

Comment: Naren, please check my last update!

Comment: yes it should be group. Also the `fetch` method is returning the empty hash (as passed second argument).

Rails is not able to parse the parameter sent via postman. try to setup the content-type in header or set the request format by appending .xml to url.

Comment: one more point, you have mentioned JSON in question title and using XML request in example!!

Comment: Thanks I will change it. so the fetch method always return an empty hash? actually I still have the same error. what would be the best way to create an object with a REST Api?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49737/discussion-between-naren-sisodiya-and-moh)

Answer (score 1):

you can try with following json payload

```
{
    'group' : {
    'title': 'your title',
    'description': 'your description',
    'user_id': 1
    }
}
```

and set the `Content-Type: application/json` in headers
also set the request format as .json in url

Comment: I did it but still not working, I think I have a problem in using strong parameters, and data are not sending to controller as well.

Comment: can you also add the request log in question.

Comment: Sorry Naren, what do you refiere by request log?

Comment: look in development/production.log file based on your environment. when you post a request the request entry made into the log file

Comment: Ah yes, I copied above what my request is creating.

Answer (score 0):

Your params need to be in the form of of properties belonging to `group`, which is your model in this case. To do that in Postman, use the URL params instead of raw to make your life easier. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Also if you wish to do it via json as in one of the answers above, make sure you change the post request from `http://0.0.0.0:3000/groups` to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/groups.json`